# How can I configure this relationship in EntityFramework (1 -> many, plus 1 -> 0 or 1, no join table)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm aware that a realistic option is to change the proposed DB Schema; I am pursuing that option too. However ... I'd like to know whether it's possible to set EF up so that it understands this structure ....

---

Business Model:

- Every Foo is associated with a Bar.
- Each Bar can have multiple Foos.
- Each Bar may also have one *special* Foo, (though it might not have one)

Enforcing consistency of "a Bar's special Foo must be associated with that Bar" is the responsibility of the Codebase, not the Database.

Enforcing consistency of "a Bar can't have more than one special Foo" would ideally be the responsibility of the Database.

---

Chosen DB Model:

As noted above, I'm aware that other possible structures exist, with many advantages to them (not least "being easier to configure in EF").

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BarId] INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Bar] FOREIGN KEY ([BarId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Bar] ([Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bar] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [SpecialFooId] INT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SpecialFoo] FOREIGN KEY ([SpecialFooId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Foo] ([Id])
);
```

---

Current Guess at Domain Model:

```
public class Foo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  // Props for easy 1-many relationship.
  public int BarId { get; set; }
  public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  // Prop for easy 1-many relationship.
  public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

  // Props for hard 1-0..1 relationship.
  public int? SpecialFooId { get; set; }
  public virtual Foo SpecialFoo { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not at all certain that this Domain Object model is the correct one for EF, and I don't have the faintest idea how to configure it.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: public virtual ICollection<Foo> Bars ? or Foo Collection

Comment: @NaDeRStar thank you, that should be `ICollection<Foo> Foos`

Comment: @NaDeRStar Fixed now

Comment: be aware of circular references in case u r going to serialize the data

Comment: @MostafaELite Agreed, and definitely worth highlighting to any future devs that find this!

Comment: Why do you doubt the model? It looks OK.

Comment: If you mean the DB model, I didn't say I doubted  out, I said that I was aware that other options exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally the reason that I couldn't make this work is that the DB Model described above, is NOT reflected by the C# Domain object model described above.

Based on that DB model, a single Foo, could be the SpecialFoo of *multiple* Bars - the FK from Bar to Foo doesn't know that business logic will ensure that there actually be at most one of those FKs pointing to any given Foo.

So, the class model needs to be:

```
public class Foo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  // Props for easy 1-many relationship.
  public int BarId { get; set; }
  public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }

  //****** THE CHANGED BIT ******
  public ICollection<Bar> BarsForWhichThisIsTheSpecialFoo { get; set; }  
  //****** THE CHANGED BIT ******
}

public class Bar
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  // Prop for easy 1-many relationship.
  public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

  // Props for hard 1-0..1 relationship.
  public int? SpecialFooId { get; set; }
  public virtual Foo SpecialFoo { get; set; }
}
```

And the correct modelbuilder incantation is then:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>()
        .HasMany(bar => bar.Foos)
        .WithRequired(foo => foo.Bar)
        .HasForeignKey(foo => foo.BarId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
        .HasMany(foo => foo.BarsForWhichThisIsTheSpecialFoo)
        .WithOptional(bar => bar.SpecialFoo)
        .HasForeignKey(bar => bar.SpecialFooId);
```

Which expresses the changed p.o.v. of the relationship: According to the DB, Bars don't really have a SpecialFoo that is theirs ... Foos have a collection of Bars for which they  are Special.

Comment: The "changed bit" isn't necessary. And in db terms records "having" an owner record is exactly what's expressed by foreign keys. Records never "have" a collection of other records.

Comment: Unless you can give an example of a structure that works without it, I'm gonna say you're wrong. I know that this world, I know why it works, and I know why the previous model didn't work.

Comment: You can model a 1:n relationship as a non-bidirectional relationship. Either the collection or the reference property is enough. Add  `HasOne(b => b.SpecialFoo).WithMany()` to `Bar`'s configuration and remove `BarsForWhichThisIsTheSpecialFoo`.

Comment: Cool - that's a much more useful input :D I'll give it a go, to see if it works. I'd prefer to be able to navigate from a Foo, to the Bar for which it's speciual, but I can probably live without that.

Comment: @GertArnold success! I hadn't realised that `WithMany()` was allowed to have no args. Do you want to add that as an answer, and I'll accept it.